# Insert data into multiple table from one table using a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have one parent table which consists of around 150 columns. I need to get the records from the parent table and insert them into 11 different child tables, which have the column names and data types.

Comment: I see no reason for PL/SQL, plain SQL will do.

Comment: Be more Specific. Do you want the Data to be same and show changes on all other tables when there is a change in any other table. or distribute rows over tables. (asked for Anubhav Srivastava)

Comment: i Just want data to be same and show changes on all other 11 tables when there is a change in Parent(main) table. i am not going to do anything  manually, with child tables.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you want someone to take time out of their busy day to help you, please spend a little time crafting a usable question.  See these links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  and http://sscce.org/  Please show sample table structure and data.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a very convenient INSERT ALL command that can help in this case.
The syntax of **unconditional** version is:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO child1( col1, col2, col3 ) VALUES( col1, col2, col3 )
  INTO child2 VALUES( col1, col2, col3 )
  INTO child3 ( col1, col2, col3 )
  INTO child4
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM parent
-- WHERE some conditions;
```

A link to a demo: --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3eb62/1

The above command retrieves all rows from the `parent` table using `SELECT ... FROM ...` (at the bottom), then, for each retrieved record, it executes all `INSERT ...` statements. 

If the `SELECT` clause has also a `WHERE conditions` clause, then only rows that meet these conditions will be inserted.
The `INSERT` part of the query in the example could have various forms:

- A full form with explicitely definied columns of source and destination tables:

  `INTO dest_table( destcol1, ... destcolN ) VALUES (sourcecol1, ..., sourcecolN)`
- A shortened form where only columns from source table are given

  `INTO dest_table VALUES (sourcecol1, ..., sourcecolN)`
- Another shortened form where only columns from destination table are given

  `INTO dest_table( destcol1, ... destcolN )`
- or the simplest:

  `INTO dest_table`

---

`INSERT ALL` has also a **conditional** version:

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN 1=1 THEN INTO child1( col1, col2, col3 ) VALUES( col1, col2, col3 )
  WHEN col1 <> 2 THEN INTO child2 VALUES( col1, col2, col3 )
  WHEN col3 < 3 THEN INTO child3 ( col1, col2, col3 )
  WHEN col2 = 'rec 3' THEN INTO child4
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM parent;
```

A link to a demo: ---> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7da3/1

This version inserts rows only when a condition specified after `WHEN` clause is meet.
For each selected rows always all conditions are evaluated.

---

There is also another **conditional** form: `INSERT FIRST`

```
INSERT FIRST
  WHEN col1 >= 4 THEN INTO child1( col1, col2, col3 ) VALUES( col1, col2, col3 )
  WHEN col1 >= 3 THEN INTO child2 VALUES( col1, col2, col3 )
  WHEN col1 >= 2 THEN INTO child3 ( col1, col2, col3 )
  WHEN col1 >= 1 THEN INTO child4
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM parent;
```

A link to a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a421e/1

Here, for each source row, Oracle evaluates conditions from top to bottom, and when some condition is true, then executes only this one `INSERT` statement, and skips remaining inserts.

**------- EDIT -------**

An example how to do it in a procedural way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE name
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT ALL
      INTO child1( col1, col2, col3 ) VALUES( col1, col2, col3 )
      INTO child2 VALUES( col1, col2, col3 )
      INTO child3 ( col1, col2, col3 )
      INTO child4
   SELECT col1, col2, col3
   FROM parent ;
   -- if commit is required, place it here
   -- COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for above answer  but actually i need to write above query in Procedural form(as a stored procedure) so that i can script it. I don't want to add or insert columns every time one by one. it should be like whenever i will run the procedure, all the data  should get inserted automatically in one go.

Comment: I appended an example of a procedure.

Comment: Sorry Mate,, i tried  but it showing an error saying that PL/SQL; SQL Statement ignored and showing a red mark near to insert all . can you please advice me what to do next. i have tried putting commas and semicolons also, but not able to rectify. :(

Comment: I am sorry, didn't mention that `INSERT ALL` works on Oracle 11 and above. On Oracle 11 it compiles fine, see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e0cf/1 If you are using Oracle 10, you must use indyvidual inserts, one insert query for each destination table.